# AVPlayer/AVPlayerViewController giving warnings when I am trying to play/stop

Tags: ios, avplayer, tvos, xcode10, avplayerviewcontroller

When I am playing video form this URL.
http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4
I am getting below warnings.

```
let videoURL = URL(string: "http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4")
player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
```

iOS:-

Here I am using AVPlayer to load URL and play video when I click on play button

> <2DAD5582-1C08-4D06-8FAF-DDDDE0681EC0>.<9> load failed with error
>   Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4,
>   _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalDataTask <2DAD5582-1C08-4D06-8FAF-DDDDE0681EC0>.<9>" ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask

TVos:- I am getting above one and also

Here I am using AVPlayerViewController to load URL and play video when I click on Selection

> [MRPlaybackQueueServiceClient] playbackQueueRequest
>   C78010B7-2A09-487A-B759-E25D701714D6 PineBoard-66026
>   /A600.000000x600.000000/R[0:1] responded to asset request with error
>   Error Domain=kMRMediaRemoteFrameworkErrorDomain Code=15 "Operation
>   requires a client data source to have been registered."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation requires a client data
>   source to have been registered.}

Comment: on iOS error code -999 means the request was cancelled (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrorcancelled?language=objc) , its impossible to speculate on why without seeing any code

Comment: Response when accessing the URL http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4 is 403 Forbidden which would explain why the asset is cancelled. Do you expect for this link to work?